# What language is this character from?

Tags: sanskrit, writing, symbol

A colleague of mine owns a ring and asked me what language this character is from:

[image]

I speak Japanese so I could pretty much rule out that and Chinese (her first guess). It's not Korean nor Thai either; to me it seems like Sanskrit. Yet I cannot find the character online.

Can someone please identify this character for me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks pretty much like either *aum* or *hrim*, as written in [Jainist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jain_symbols) traditional script. Check [here](http://mydocumentstore.blogspot.com/2013/10/god-symbol.html) and [here](http://www.jainpushp.org/symbols.htm)

Comment: I tend to agree with bytebuster and fdb: the bulk of the character looks a lot like the 'a' character in Devanagari. People don't write 'a' like that these days, but the [old form](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Devanagari_a_old.svg/64px-Devanagari_a_old.svg.png) looked somewhat like that. With the (rhomboidal) circle on top, it might as well be 'om'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the sacred syllable “om” in a rather stylised Devanagari script. In plain unicode text: आँ

Comment: Somebody seems to think this answer is wrong. I would be glad to hear any other suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This is the syllable "Om" (ॐ) written in Ranjana script from Nepal

Images of different variations can be [searched on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ranjana%20lipi%20om&rlz=1C1CHBD_enKR885KR885&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=VOI77nbVOiMi-M%252Cuyxva1DOg8YGTM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQiR7WfZW-YHobRHnBbq6VV2dDY_Q&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxpKi90uvyAhWSaN4KHSu5DwAQ9QF6BAgVEAE#imgrc=RdyFR1DP2HVJIM&imgdii=iCtz6C-ryXUcHM)